# How to fix enqueue_styles error for a twenty-seventeen childtheme

Tags: functions, child-theme, errors, wp-enqueue-style

I have searched your site but cannot find and fix this error I get:

`Notice: Function wp_enqueue_style was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the <code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>, <code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>, or <code>login_enqueue_scripts</code> hooks. This notice was triggered by the <code>editor-buttons</code> handle. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 5835`

**In my functions.php I have:**

```
//from: https://kinsta.com/blog/twenty-seventeen-theme/
// Also found: https://make.wordpress.org/training/handbook/lesson-plans/theme-school/child-themes/child-themes-twentyseventeen/
function childtheme_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( 'parent-style' ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_enqueue_styles' );
 
 
 // Method 2: Exclude a Category from WordPress Homepage Using Code
 // As at: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-exclude-a-category-from-your-wordpress-homepage/
 function exclude_webapps_home( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home ) {
$query->set( 'cat', '-49' ); // MUST use 'cat' for category and '-ID' for category ID
}
return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_webapps_home' );

?>
```

**What must I change? Can you help?**
I have no plugins or messed otherwise with the *editor-buttons*.
I am on WordPress 6.1

Comment: Like the error message says, you need to call `wp_enqueue_style` only from within certain hooks. Whatever is _calling_ `childtheme_enqueue_styles` is doing it wrong (though the caller and this function are probably both from the same provider).

Comment: @tripleee I have nowhere else childtheme_enqueue_styles called. This is the only place.

Comment: This is the definition of the function, something is _calling_ the function in order for the error message to trigger. Search for `childtheme_enqueue_styles()` without `function` in front of it.

Comment: @tripleee Where should I look? The code I provided is the whole of my functions.php What must I correct in my functions.php?

Comment: Something is calling it; the fact that it's in `includes` probably means something else will `include` it when it runs.

Comment: It's not the function from your theme creating the error, the error message refers specifically to the `editor-buttons` handle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with this code below.

```
function childtheme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), wp_get_theme()->parent()->get('Version') );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array( 'parent-style' ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version') // Note you must provide a version into the child theme
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just tried it. Unfortunately there is no difference.